# ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE when loading a device driver

Tags: windows, driver, device

There are a lot of stuff on the internet about this, but none is specific to me. I load a device driver from a file with the following code:

```
    hService = OpenService (hManager, TC_DRIVER_NAME, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (hService != NULL)
    {
        // Now stop it
        SERVICE_STATUS status;
        if (::ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &status))
        { 
            int nLoop = 0;
            while (::QueryServiceStatus(hService, &status) && nLoop < 3)
            { 
                if (status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
                {
                    Sleep(500);     
                    nLoop++;                                                        
                    continue;
                }
                if (status.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED)                                                 
                    break;
            }
        } 
        // Remove stale service (driver is not loaded but service exists)
        DeleteService (hService);
        int n = GetLastError();
        CloseServiceHandle (hService);
        Sleep(500);
}

    hService = CreateService(....
```

My problem is that if my application crashes - or when in Visual Studio I stop debugging without exiting the app properly - then the DeleteService and CreateService will always fail with error 1072 (ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE). I have tried many things like changing the registry values in currentControlSet, even deleting them all, but only a reboot manages to enable me to carry on normally. I guess some handles are probably not closed properly, but is there a way to force the device driver to delete properly without a reboot?

As a precaution I have added an exception handler with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to unload the driver and that helps a bit, but if I kill the process, it doesnt get called and of course, then only a reboot enables me to reload the driver.

Thanks